# FATAL ERRORS with compilation after installing Aspose.Cells library for C++

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, aspose

Can someone please help me with my issue with Aspose.Cells library for C++?

I was writing my first C++ programme using Aspose.Cells library. Everything seemed smooth except that the following error was produced after I built the file:

Error before I launch is:

```
"Error exist in a required project.Continue launch?"
Error after running the code is:
"**fatal error: boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp: No such file or directory**".**
```

If I commented out the line `#<include Aspose.Cells.h>`, the file can run with no errors.

I tried to solve the error by installing Boost library for C++ from zip file "boost_1_73_0", as I think Aspose depends on Boost to run. However, I couldn't link to Boost successfully as there doesn't seem to be a "include" folder  and "lib" folder for me to add into project properties.

My questions are:

1. Will installing Boost solve my problem?
2. If yes, how can I install Boost library successful?

The following is my code in C++. Thanks a Lot in advance!

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <Aspose.Cells.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!I am little red!!!" << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Regards
Hillary

UPDATE: I have successfully installed and linked Boot library now but I have got three warning message upon building: "Ignoring #pragma warning [-wunknown-pragmas]" , are these warning messages serious?
I also ran into another fatal error: unicode/uloc.h:No such file or directory. How can I correctly link up to unilib-master/Unicode library?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, installing Boost helps.

If Aspose only requires header-only libraries from Boost, then you don't have to do much. The "include" path you're looking for is just the folder where you extracted the zip. The actual library headers are under `boost/` in that folder, which are then found by the compiler.

If you need the shared libraries, you will need to build them. Follow the steps here [Getting Started On Windows](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/more/getting_started/windows.html)

Comment: Thank you very much Sehe. I have successfully installed and linked Boot library now but I have got three warning message upon building: "Ignoring #pragma warning [-wunknown-pragmas]" , are these warning messages serious? I also ran into a new fatal error: unicode/uloc.h:No such file or directory. Can you tell me how I can correctly link up to unilib-master/Unicode library? Thank you!